# Sitecore field value being truncated at 255 characters?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, glass-mapper

I am encountering an issue where the value of string -- stored in a Single-Line Text field -- is returned as being truncated to the first 255 characters.   When I look in the Content Editor, I see the excess characters.  If I query the database using Sitecore Rocks I see the extra characters.

Is it possible this is being caused by GlassMapper?

In the code samples below, it is the LinkText that is being truncated.

My models...

```
using Glass.Mapper.Sc.Configuration.Attributes;
using Glass.Mapper.Sc.Fields;
using MySite.Extensions;
using MySite.Models.Base;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using System;

namespace MySite.Models.Items
{
    [SitecoreType]
  public class LinkItem : ISitecoreBase, ILinkItemBase
  {
    // ISitecoreBase
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Path { get; set; }
    public virtual Item InnerItem { get; set; }

    // ILinkItemBase
    public virtual string LinkText { get; set; }
    public virtual Link LinkTarget { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Does the link have neccessary content?
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool IsValid()
    {
      return this.LinkText.HasValue();
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
using Glass.Mapper.Sc.Configuration.Attributes;
using Glass.Mapper.Sc.Fields;
using MySite.Extensions;

namespace MySite.Models.Base
{
    [SitecoreType(TemplateId = Constants.TemplateIds.LINK_ITEM_BASE)]
  public interface ILinkItemBase
  {
    [SitecoreField(Constants.LinkItemBase.LINK_TEXT)]
    string LinkText { get; }

    [SitecoreField(Constants.LinkItemBase.LINK_TARGET)]
    Link LinkTarget { get; }
  }
}
```

---

The logic snippet... by line 3 of GetLinkItems, the LinkText of the items in this.LinkItems is already showing up as truncated.

```
public virtual IEnumerable<LinkItem> LinkItems { get; set; }

public ICollection<LinkItem> GetLinkItems()
    {
      ICollection<LinkItem> linkItemCollection = new List<LinkItem>();

      if (this.LinkItems.HasItems())
      {
        foreach (LinkItem LinkItem in this.LinkItems)
        {
          if (LinkItem.IsValid())
          {
            linkItemCollection.Add(LinkItem);
          }
        }
      }

      return linkItemCollection;
    }
```

Comment: Before you cast the item to glass object, Can you check the field value? Does it have the complete text there?

Comment: What version of glass are you using? I tried on version 4 and is working as expected.

Comment: @AhmedOkour As I am casting using an annotation in the Model, where would I place the debug point to see the value before the cast?

Comment: @SitecoreClimber It appears I am using 4.0.5.54

Comment: @eat-sleep-code In your InnerItem property, You can check the actual field value, like this 
LinkItem.InnerItem[Constants.LinkItemBase.LINK_TEXT]